# Google Cloud Speech API: Real Time recognition via REST

Tags: android, rest, speech-recognition, google-cloud-platform, grpc

I am interested in performing real time speech to text using [Google cloud speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/). I saw in the documentation that is possible to do real time speech to text when it comes to [gRPC API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rpc/)

However I can't see anything about real time processing in [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/), that means it is not possible to do the real time speech to text in REST?

FYI I am trying to implement this to my android application.

Answer (score 3):

This was [asked recently in the discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/cloud-speech-discuss/Ie8f-GZ_VYI/sLsEKGXUAQAJ).

Unfortunately the answer was no and there was no schedule for it to be implemented. I already added my '+1' to the discussion, as it's something I need.

If you want to attempt gRPC in the mean time, [check out this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/plM11au46oc), which has some links to example code, that leads to other samples.

Comment: @PeakGen It's definitely possible. Their Chromium duplex Speech API works as a RESTful service. It's fantastic, but limited to personal/development use only. I hope they 'port' that implementation over asap...

Comment: OK, gRPC is confusing. It seems like I have to run both server and client? Even though in gRPC site I can see Java-Android, I can't see any successful implementation for google speech

Comment: @PeakGen added a link for you in the answer. I didn't attempt it personally, as I want the control a REST implementation provides. Actually, I'd rather that Google just sorted out their 'native' offering via Google Now and make it more comprehensive..... Not having access to the raw audio via their Recognition Service is bordering on a joke.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the link